# How to apply theme to ExpressionTemplate using configuration file in Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I would like to customize my console output logs using Serilog. I found how to configure this with Expression Templates using code:

```cs
.WriteTo.Console(new ExpressionTemplate("[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3}] {@m}\n{@x}", theme: TemplateTheme.Code));
```

But when I apply it to my yaml configuration, I get this error:

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create instance of type 'Serilog.Formatting.ITextFormatter' because it is either abstract or an interface.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, Object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.Get(IConfiguration configuration, Type type, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.Get(IConfiguration configuration, Type type)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ObjectArgumentValue.ConvertTo(Type toType, ResolutionContext resolutionContext)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.<>c__DisplayClass21_2.<CallConfigurationMethods>b__3(<>f__AnonymousType9`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier0)
   at System.Linq.Utilities.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListPartitionIterator`2.ToList()
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.CallConfigurationMethods(ILookup`2 methods, IList`1 configurationMethods, Object receiver)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.ApplySinks(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.Configure(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
   at Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSettingsConfiguration.Settings(ILoggerSettings settings)
   at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, String sectionName, DependencyContext dependencyContext)
   at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, DependencyContext dependencyContext)
   at SowaLabs.Views.Web.Common.ServiceUtils.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<RunService>b__1(HostBuilderContext buildContext, ILoggingBuilder logging) in C:\GitHub\BisonDataNueva2\dotnet\src\Views.Web.Common\Common\ServiceUtils.cs:line 133
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<ConfigureLogging>b__1(ILoggingBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configure)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ConfigureLogging>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection collection)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
```

My configuration file looks like this:

```yaml
Serilog:
  Using:
  - Serilog.Sinks.Console
  - Serilog.Sinks.File
  - Serilog.Expressions
  WriteTo:
    - Name: Console
      Args:
        Formatter:
          Type: "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions"
          Template: "[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3} ({Substring(SourceContext, LastIndexOf(SourceContext, '.') + 1)})] {@m}\n{@x}"
          Theme: "Serilog.Templates.Themes.TemplateTheme::Code, Serilog.Expressions"
  Enrich:
    - FromLogContext
    - WithMachineName
    - WithThreadId
```

Comment: You might need to grab the latest preview version of _Serilog.Settings.Configuration_ for this to work. You'll also probably need to use `$type` instead of `Type`, and lowercase names for `template` and `theme`.

Comment: Got fixed by https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/287 after 3.3.0 release.